# Combining the use of preceding and following sibling in the same xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[following-sibling::td/div/a[@title="bet365"] and preceding-sibling::td/span[@class=" odds-wrap " and @eu="1.90"]]')
for ele in element:
    print(ele.text)
```

I need to get content of  `<td> 161.5 </td>`

But this does not work..

Where I was wrong?

Comment: I think you have to change `following-sibling` for `preceding-sibling` and the same for the other.

Comment: I tried but it does not work..

Comment: Any reason why you are checking both the siblings to get to the required td? Simpler would be to use parent two times or ancestor on the 'a' tag with the title attribute and td following-sibling with index 1

Comment: I know, thank you, but I have to check both

Comment: @JakeSully365 Try this - //td[preceding-sibling::td[1]/div/a[@title='bet365'] and following-sibling::td/span[@class=' odds-wrap '][@eu='1.90']]

Comment: Finally.. Thank you very much!